# product options variation

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, custom-options, product-view

I am looking to present custom-options as a link to another product.

Maybe someone will be able to tell me, or maybe there is an existing module/tutorial that will help me implement this.

Example:
https://comfy.ua/smartfon-samsung-a305-galaxy-a30-4-64gb-black.html

Comment: What do you need? Is not clear

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/bWRKhdB/test.png